# how can read and write xlsx file in netsuite suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

how can read direcly xlsx file and save it from suitescript.
Iam tring using exceljs but it not propely in server script.

```js
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile('../datafiles/mydata.xlsx').then(() => {
    var sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("data");
    console.log(sheet.actualRowCount)
    for (var i = 1; i <= sheet.actualRowCount; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= sheet.actualColumnCount; j++) {
            data = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString();
            process.stdout.write(data+" ");
            // console.log(data)
        }
        console.log()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check my implementation in SuiteScript 2.x for writing XLSX file using external library (no coloring, formatting, etc..).

It's very basic and it's only for proof of concept, check it here:
https://github.com/gmihaylov/netsuite-saved-search-export-excel-xlsx

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have a server script:
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/runtime', 'N/file', 'N/search', 'N/render', 'N/encode', 'N/record', 'N/redirect'],
function(ui, runtime, file, search, render, encode, record, redirect) {

```
function generateXLS(){
    var url;
    try {
        log.debug('generateXLS','* * S T A R T * * ->' + runtime.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage());

        xmlString = generateXlsHeader(objData);
        xmlString += generateXlsBody(objData);
        name = 'Excel_Information_' + objData.customerData.internalId + '.xls';
        base64EncodedString = encode.convert({
                string: xmlString,
                inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
                outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64
            });
        base64EncodedString = base64EncodedString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
        objExcel = file.create({
                    name: name,
                    fileType: file.Type.EXCEL,
                    contents: base64EncodedString
                });

        repFolderID = 1234;
        if (isEmpty(repFolderID)) {
                throw 'repFolderID missing';
        }
        objExcel.folder = repFolderID;
        fileId = objExcel.save();
        fileObj = file.load({
                id: fileId
        });
        url = fileObj.url;
        log.debug('generateXLS','* * E N D * * ->' + runtime.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage());
    } catch (error) {
        log.error('generateXLS', error);
    }
    return url;

}

function onRequest(context) {
    generateXLS();
}

return {
    onRequest: onRequest
};
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your code, in this method Im using file.load(‘myfile.xml’) and then save loaded content with file.Type.XMLDOC and encode:file.Encoding.UTF8
To saving Json object to csv or Excel, im using alasql,xlsx for quick performant

Comment: is there any way to save file in .xlsx instead of .xls?